# How to print 2 endless loop side by side on Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, terminal, printing

I tried to design a function in Python with while True loop. And this function prints a word which i want. All i want is running this function side by side on different lines and print "hello world" on terminal. It feels function works true but my problem is running this function on terminal side by side too many times. How can i solve that?

```
import time 

        
def WordFinder(word):
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    for i in a:
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if i == a[a.index(word) - 1]:
            while True:
                print(word)
                time.sleep(0.05)


print(WordFinder("h"))
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what should your terminal side-by-side view look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the threading module. Here's an example that runs the WordFinder function 3 times side by side:

```
import threading
import time
import os

def WordFinder(word):
    a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for i in a:
        print(i, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if i == a[a.index(word) - 1]:
            while True:
                print(f"\r{word}", end='', flush=True)
                time.sleep(0.05)

threads = []
for i in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=WordFinder, args=("h",))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
    print() 

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This will run the WordFinder function 3 times side by side, with each instance printing its output on a different line.